# Magento2: Need To change Purchase Order Payment Code

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, purchase-order

I want to change Magento2 Offline payment method "Purchase Order" payment Code,with separate module. Do not suggest Make a new Offline payment methods like purchase order.

**Current-code: "purchaseorder"**

Thanks

Comment: you mean you want to override the current purchase order and change its payment code?

Comment: Separate module is recommended and disable the "Purchase Order" seem that better

Answer (score 6):

It would be great if you can create a custom payment method like a Purchase order rather than change payment method code. I have explained all the steps for creating a new offline custom payment method using a custom module same as Purchase Order.

1 Create Registration.php file app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Indianic_FortoxFinance',
    __DIR__
);
```

2 Create module.xml file (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/module.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Indianic_FortoxFinance" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Store"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_OfflinePayments"/>
            <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3 Create payment.xml file in custom module (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/payment.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <groups>
        <group id="offline">
            <label>Offline Payment Methods</label>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <methods>
        <method name="fortoxfinance">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

4 Create config.xml file in custom module (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <fortoxfinance>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Indianic\FortoxFinance\Model\FortoxFinance</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Fortox Finance</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </fortoxfinance>
            <free>
                <group>offline</group>
            </free>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

5 Create system.xml file in custom module. (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/adminhtml/system.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="fortoxfinance" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Fortox Finance</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                    <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="51" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="min_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="98" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                </field>
                <field id="max_order_total" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="99" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Maximum Order Total</label>
                </field>
                <field id="model"></field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

6 Create Model file in the custom module. (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Model/FortoxFinance.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Indianic\FortoxFinance\Model;
/**
 * Cash on delivery payment method model
 *
 * @method \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodExtensionInterface getExtensionAttributes()
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class FortoxFinance extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{
    /*
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'fortoxfinance';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_formBlockType = \Indianic\FortoxFinance\Block\Form\FortoxFinance::class;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_infoBlockType = \Indianic\FortoxFinance\Block\Info\FortoxFinance::class;

    /**
     * Assign data to info model instance
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject|mixed $data
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
    {
        $this->getInfoInstance()->setPoNumber($data->getPoNumber());
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Validate payment method information object
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @api
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        parent::validate();

        if (empty($this->getInfoInstance()->getPoNumber())) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Purchase order number is a required field.'));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

7 Create checkout_index_index file in (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="fortox-payments" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Indianic_FortoxFinance/js/view/payment/fortox-payments</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="fortoxfinance" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

8 Create js file fortox-payments.js file in (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/fortox-payments.js)

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* @api */
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
], function (Component, rendererList) {
    'use strict';

    rendererList.push(
        {
            type: 'fortoxfinance',
            component: 'Indianic_FortoxFinance/js/view/payment/method-renderer/fortoxfinance-method'
        }
    );

    /** Add view logic here if needed */
    return Component.extend({});
});
```

9 Create js file fortoxfinance-method.js file in (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/fortoxfinance-method.js)

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* @api */
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'jquery',
    'mage/validation'
], function (Component, $) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Indianic_FortoxFinance/payment/fortoxfinance-form',
            purchaseOrderNumber: ''
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('purchaseOrderNumber');
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @return {Object}
         */
        getData: function () {
            return {
                method: this.item.method,
                'po_number': this.purchaseOrderNumber(),
                'additional_data': null
            };
        },
        /**
         * @return {jQuery}
         */
        validate: function () {
            var form = 'form[data-role=fortoxfinance-form]';
            return $(form).validation() && $(form).validation('isValid');
        }
    });
});
```

10 Create HTML file fortoxfinance-form.html in (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/web/template/payment/fortoxfinance-form.html)

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label">
            <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <form id="fortoxfinance-form" class="form form-purchase-order" data-role="fortoxfinance-form">
            <fieldset class="fieldset payment method" data-bind='attr: {id: "payment_form_" + getCode()}'>
                <div class="field field-number required">
                    <label for="po_number" class="label">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Purchase Order Number'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text"
                               id="po_number"
                               name="payment[po_number]"
                               data-validate="{required:true}"
                               data-bind='
                                attr: {title: $t("Purchase Order Number")},
                                value: purchaseOrderNumber'
                               class="input-text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar" id="review-buttons-container">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        data-role="review-save">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

11 Create block file i.e FortoxFinance.php (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Block/Form/FortoxFinance.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Indianic\FortoxFinance\Block\Form;

class FortoxFinance extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form
{
    /**
     * Purchase order template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Indianic_FortoxFinance::form/fortoxfinance.phtml';
}
```

12 Create another block file i.e FortoxFinance.php (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Block/Info/FortoxFinance.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Indianic\FortoxFinance\Block\Info;

class FortoxFinance extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Indianic_FortoxFinance::info/fortoxfinance.phtml';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function toPdf()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('Indianic_FortoxFinance::info/pdf/fortoxfinance.phtml');
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
}
```

13 Create template file fortoxfinance.phtml (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/templates/form/fortoxfinance.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Purchaseorder
 */
$methodCode = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode());
?>
<fieldset class="fieldset items <?= /* @noEscape */ $methodCode ?>" id="payment_form_<?= /* @noEscape */ $methodCode ?>" style="display: none">
    <div class="field number required">
        <label for="po_number" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchase Order Number')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="po_number" name="payment[po_number]" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchase Order Number')) ?>"
                   class="input-text required-entry"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getInfoData('po_number')) ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

14 Create another template file fortoxfinance.phtml (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/templates/info/fortoxfinance.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Purchaseorder
 */
?>
<dl class="payment-method purchase order">
    <dt class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></dt>
    <dd class="content">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchase Order Number')) ?></strong>
        <span class="number"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getInfo()->getPoNumber()) ?></span>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

15 Create template file fortoxfinance.phtml (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/adminhtml/templates/info/pdf/fortoxfinance.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Purchaseorder
 */
?>
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchase Order Number: %1', $block->getInfo()->getPoNumber())) ?>
    {{pdf_row_separator}}
```

16 Create template file fortoxfinance.phtml (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/adminhtml/templates/info/fortoxfinance.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Info\Purchaseorder
 */
?>
<div class="order-payment-method-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></div>
<table class="data-table admin__table-secondary">
    <tr>
        <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchase Order Number')) ?>:</th>
        <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getInfo()->getPoNumber()) ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

17 Create template file fortoxfinance.phtml (app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/adminhtml/templates/form/fortoxfinance.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Purchaseorder
 */
?>
<fieldset class="admin__fieldset payment-method" id="payment_form_<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethodCode()) ?>" style="display: none">
    <div class="admin__field _required">
        <label for="po_number" class="admin__field-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Purchase Order Number')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="admin__field-control">
            <input type="text" id="po_number" name="payment[po_number]"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Purchase Order Number")) ?>" class="required-entry admin__control-text"
                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getInfoData('po_number') ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is such a beautifully crafted answer, Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

The carrier codes are defined in the core files of Magento.

### **I do not recommend you adjusting the core files but i will tell you how to change them.**

If you upgrade your Magento all adjustments will be reverted. You can apply these changes with a module.

```
 Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder
```

change

```
const PAYMENT_METHOD_PURCHASEORDER_CODE = 'purchaseorder';
```

and     `module-offline-payments/etc/config.xml`

change

```
   <purchaseorder>
        <active>0</active>
        <model>Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder</model>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>Purchase Order</title>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <group>offline</group>
    </purchaseorder>
```

to

```
        <yourname>
            <active>0</active>
            <model>Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder</model>
            <order_status>pending</order_status>
            <title>Purchase Order</title>
            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            <group>offline</group>
        </yourname>
```

Also `module-offline-payments\etc\payment.xml`

change

```
 <method name="purchaseorder">
        <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
    </method>
```

to

```
<method name="yourname">
    <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
</method>
```

then you need to adjust the group in `module-offline-payments\etc\config.xml`

```
<group id="purchaseorder" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="32" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
```

to

```
<group id="yourname" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="32" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
```

After that you need to edit everything that providers the frontend JS

```
module-offline-payments/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

change

```
<item name="yourname" xsi:type="array"> 
<item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

and last `module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/offline-payments.js`

change

```
{
    type: 'yourname',
    component: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/purchaseorder-method'
}
```

**You can see that this includes changing a whole lot of things.** Not even taking in account the already saved data that you need so change in the database.
With plugins you might be able to intercept the `getPaymentMethod()` from the Order/Invoice/Shipment/Credit memo and change it from there but without the explanation why you would change it i do not know your needs.

It would be a lot less risky and more stable to just write a new payment method. It is not that hard to do and you can extend existing Magento classes for it.

### **So i highly recommend creating a new payment method instead of adjusting the existing ones.**

[Link to documentation about new payment method here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html)

And then you would just disable purchase order and enable this one.
You could even let it extend the purchase order class.