# Payment method option not visible on backend (under sales) Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

We are facing an issue that Payment method under Sales from admin side gone...
You can see on my screen shot, no error or somthing from the logs.

[image]

I belive it is configuration on code that changed, to be unvisible on admin side.
By the way from front end, I still see the correct payment method show up as we configured before...

Please let me know if someone have suggestion, where can I check configuration from admin side(backend).

Comment: Any third-party extension you've installed which impact this?

Comment: I try this one, but after I remove it, do you see any impact for it? evan that I remove it after...https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264034/magento2-need-to-change-purchase-order-payment-code

Comment: I copied all the vendor/magento and the option back, Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! Means vendor files are missing from your Magento installation.